# How to add Price field to Odoo Product template?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-website

I am using this free Odoo data slider module on website.
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/9.0/website_snippet_data_slider/
A nice module and works well too.I need to add "price" field in to this as currently it displays product name only.

[image]

Accordingly to this module we can add fields to slider from product.template to this section

https://github.com/laslabs/odoo-website/blob/9.0/website_snippet_data_slider/static/src/js/data_slider.js#L131

have tried to add price field like this

this.priceField = this.widgetOptions.data_price_field;
this.fields = [this.priceField, 'lst_price'];

unfortunate it doesn't work.Can anyone point me the reason and fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to map the value of the price to an html element. I have not tested this however if you take a look at data_slider.js just follow what is done for the display_name (product name `data_name_field`) from top to bottom.

You will also want to do some formatting for currency and so on. This should get you going in the right direction. Good luck!

In `data_slider.js` try making the following changes.

Below line 27 add:

```
data_price_field: 'price',
```

Below line 125 add:

```
this.priceField = this.widgetOptions.data_price_field;
```

Replace line 131 with:

```
this.fields = [this.nameField, this.priceField, 'id'];
```

Below line 96 add:

```
var $price = $('<h5>').text("Price " + record[this.fields[1]]);
```

Replace line 97 with:

```
var $caption = $('<div class="caption">').append($title).append($price);
```